# Moodle result data displaying in expected format

Tags: mysql, moodle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3sTo.png)Please help me in displaying the moodle gradebook data in following format by using mysql queries as I am not that good in sql queries.I want the data in following format.

Stud_id   Stud_name  Course_id1_grade  Course_id2_grade

1         ABC        B                 A+
2         PQR        C                 B+
3 ..
so on.

Thanks

Comment: There are a bunch of ad-hoc queries for Moodle here - https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports - If you are developing for Moodle then you really need to know SQL. Here are some free tutorials : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp and https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql.

Comment: Thanks russell but I didn't get any query as I wanted those are same which I ran before will you suggest me any query for displaying data in above format.